# Snapping value = 0 in Qgis

Tags: python, qgis-3, python-script-tool, snapping

I am building pipes network, I need check connection between of pipes. I want to pipes must snap and tolerance has value = 0. Is there any tool to check and fix this things. I know Topology Checker Plugin, but this plugin is not limit about tolerance.

Comment: What about GRASS GIS library called [`v.clean`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass77/manuals/v.clean.html)?

Comment: @Taras many thanks, but is there way to check tolerance of 2 pipes there is value = 0?, check them then use v.clean.

Comment: @Taras or check pipes to define them there is tolerance value > 0, then we will use v.clean